What are Bangladesh's options if India doesn't hand over Sheikh Hasina?
The fleeing PM of Bangladesh, Sheikh Hasina, is now in a safe house in India.
Bangladesh's revolutionary government is preparing to formally ask India to hand her over to the government.
https://www.livemint.com/news/bangladesh-may-request-to-extradite-sheikh-hasina-from-india-creates-embarrassing-situation-11725101797639.html
What are Bangladesh's options if India don't want to hand Hasina over?

Could you provide a little bit of context on who Sheikh Hasina is and why the Bangladeshi government wants her?

Hmmm, not to give a cr*p and let her go?  There is no existential reason for Bangladesh to pursue her, energy might be better used to ensure better rulers going forward.  And esp wrt getting into an unwinnable dispute w India.

Bangladesh could do lots of things, but will want to keep it proportional. No point in starting a war over it.

@quarague That's kind of a trivial question if one has followed Bangladeshi politics at all over the past several months.

@Allure That is true but it would still be nice if people who have not followed Bangladeshi politics could still get a rough idea what this question is about. A sentence or two would suffice and make this a much better question. I didn't vote in any way but right now the question stands at -3 plus 2 close votes. I believe that is because of the missing context.

Bangladesh has a wide range of options. The more drastic measures are also much more risky. There are options ranging from the almost purely symbolic to extreme escalations, among them:

Deliver a diplomatic note.
Recall diplomatic staff.
Make a case in the International Criminal Court that her actions do fall under the categories covered by that court.
Increase tariffs on imports from India (e.g. electricity, fuel) or exports to India.
Ban commercial air travel between India and Bangladesh.
Ban any trade between India and Bangladesh.
Declare a naval blockade and try to enforce it (they might be unlikely to win, but they might get lucky).
Declare war and invade (same issues as above).

Just how far they are going to go will depend on their estimate of the likelihood of success and the cost to their own economy.

You might wish to be a bit more explicit that this is an incomplete list. For example, other options include pushing for UN General Assembly resolutions or Security Council actions, or attempting an extraction with special forces, or asking nicely again, etc...

@JoelHarmon, added a sentence in that regard.

Ironically, Bangladesh ratified the ICC treaty under Hasina https://www.pgaction.org/ilhr/rome-statute/bangladesh.html India however is not a member and probably doesn't plan to become one.

As for increasing the costs of your energy [you import], that worked so well in Europe. I guess you could add the 'Ukrainian option': blow up the hydro-dams from which India sells said energy. Less jokingly, the might be able to find people to do it https://apnews.com/article/india-hydro-energy-climate-renewables-dams-da673164d0b0a653a2291f4cab16742a I guess you could add "covertly sponsor terrorism in the neighboring country and hope they don't get enough incriminating evidence of the link".

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever, I listed an open declaration of war as an option. A terrorist attack would be something else.
